# Does a delegate member cause circular dependency?

Tags: c#, delegates, circular-reference

Background: I was building a class with a state-like machine (for fun) and have become confused about delegates.

Would the following cause a circular reference?

```cs
  public class MyClass
  {
    public Action act;
    public MyClass() { act = Foo; }

    public void Foo() { /*...*/ }
  }
```

Where Action holds a reference to the object that holds a reference to the action... and so on?

Thanks.

Comment: If `Foo` invokes `act`, then you are very likely to blow away your stack (through recursion). Otherwise, there's usually nothing wrong. You get circular reference problems if, for example, _Assembly A_ has a reference to _Assembly B_ and _B_ has a reference to _A_. At that point, the loader can't load either of them.

Comment: This does create a circular reference in the object graph; however, the .NET garbage collector can detect these cycles and collect both the object and the delegate when none of them are accessible from anywhere else, so it will not leak memory. This *would* be a problem, though, if you were implementing this in a language/runtime that uses a reference counting based GC.

Comment: @JosephDaSilva, that's what I thought. I have worked in the past with a few interops that don't play well with circular obj references, so I was curious. Thanks.